# How to use normal imports and top-level await at the same time?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, ts-node, ts-node-dev

I want to use imports (`import x from y`) and top-level awaits at the same time with ts-node. However if I change my `tsconfig.compilerOptions.module` to `es2017` or higher as required by top-level awaits I get:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

The fix for this is according to countless GH issues and SO questions to set `tsconfig.compilerOptions.module` to `commonjs` which in turn results in:

```
Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', or 'nodenext', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher
```

How can I have both? There has to be a way...

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2017",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "x",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "main.js",
  "type": "module",
  ...
}
```

I am using Node LTS (v16.14.2) and TypeScript 4.6.3.

Comment: You must use `"type": "module"` in your package.json when running a project using ESM.

Comment: @catgirlkelly I just edited in the `package.json`. I already did that to no avail :/

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71099311/top-level-await-and-import-in-typescript

Comment: @y.rashi That answer is nonsense. I added a comment to it explaining why. But thank you for linking it anyway :)

Comment: @leonheess check out my answer, it seems to work on my machine

Comment: @leonheess Have you found a solution? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: @Zapnuk Unfortunately I had to pass on top-level awaits